# If navigate back to the previous page, will the code resume where it left off?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to do something like this:

```
private async Task<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SelectAPlatypus()
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp;
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(DuckbillPage));
. . .
```

...and then have the code's execution continue where the ellipsis dots are after the user navigates back from the DuckbillPage. Will this work? Or after leaving a page in this way does a return to it take you back to the NavigatedTo() event only, and not return to the prior code?

If so, is creating an in-page Popup-like dialog a a viable/feasible option (as opposed to navigating to a different page)?

I know I can check for a condition or variable state in the original page's NavigatedTo() event, but I don't want to get any more "clever" than I have to. I'm trying to avoid making a batch of Rube Goldberg spaghetti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest of the method will execute regardless if the Frame navigates. You can write a Modal Dialog to show instead of navigating.

Using a task as the Show() method for the Modal Dialog, you could pause code execution and wait for the dialog to close before executing the rest of the method.

Comment: Does anybody have any examples of doing that (modal dialog) or links?

Comment: I do have a modal dialog class at home that I use. I can post it up after work for everyone, if you would like. It also requires an interface for the content (so that we can control the content from within the ModalDialog.)